# Can't get parameters from URL. Django

Tags: django

Few days ago I started to learn Django. I have a problem with URL parameter. 
My `views.py` function:

```
def hotel(request, id):
    return HttpResponse(id)
```

My `urls.py` code:

```
re_path(r'^hotel/(?P<id>)[\d]/$', views.hotel)
```

And when I load the page like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hotel/4/`. `HttpResponse` shows me nothing. `id = None`. Why? How can I take this `id == 4`?

Comment: Why re_path? Use path instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. between the parenthesis, you did *not* match anything, indeed, you wrote `(?P<id>)`, so the integer is captured later, and not in the `id` group; and
2. you forgot the `+` quantifier. This means `\d` will match *exactly one* digit.

You can fix this by rewriting the path to:

```
re_path(r'^hotel/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.hotel),
```

That being said, like [@sam says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61954703/cant-get-parameters-from-url-django#comment109577634_61954703) using path converters is likely more convenient and less error prone, you can define [**`path`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#path) with:

```
path('hotel/<int:id>', views.hotel)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
path('hotel/<int:id>/', views.hotel)
```

As your `id` is an integer, this is a cleaner way to go about it.